# Ltac tactic that accepts an arbitrary number of quantifiers

Tags: coq, ltac

I'm trying to write a--my first--Coq tactic.
It should split `forall x y z ..., A <-> B` into two: `forall x y z ..., A -> B` and `forall x y z ..., B -> A`.

This is my first attempt:

```
Ltac iff_split H :=
  match type of H with
  | forall x y, ?A <-> ?B =>
    let Hr := fresh H "r" in
    let Hl := fresh H "l" in
    assert (Hr : forall x y, A -> B) by (apply H);
    assert (Hl : forall x y, B -> A) by (apply H);
    clear H
  end.
```

It works only for a fixed number of quantifiers (in this case just 2), but I want to extend it to accept an arbitrary list of them.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses a trick (for expert only ) due to Adam Chlipala.
Don't hesitate to ask for more explanation if something is unclear.

`Ltac` does not allow to go under binder but you can trick it by
folding the quantifiers.
Let us take `forall x y, x + y = 0` that is a nested universal quantification.
You can fold it in into `forall p, fst p + snd p = 0` that is a simple quantification. If you can arbitrary fold and unfold nested quantifications, you are done: you fold, perform your transformation then unfold.

Here is the code that does the trick

```
Ltac fold_forall f :=
  let rec loop F := 
    match F with
      | forall x y, @?body x y => 
          let v := (eval cbv beta in (forall t, body (fst t) (snd t))) in
          loop v 
      |  _ => F
    end 
  in  loop (forall _ : unit, f).

Ltac unfold_forall f :=
  let rec loop F := 
    match F with
      | forall t : _ * _, @?body t =>
         let v := (eval cbv beta in (forall x y, (body (x, y)))) in
         loop v
      |  _ => match eval simpl in F with
              | _ -> ?G => G 
              end
    end 
  in loop f.

Ltac mk_left f :=
   match f with
    | forall x : ?T, ?A <-> ?B => constr:(forall x : T, A -> B)
   end.

Ltac mk_right f :=
   match f with
    | forall x : ?T, ?A <-> ?B => constr:(forall x : T, B -> A)
   end.

Ltac my_tac  H := 
 match type of H with
 | ?v => let v1 := fold_forall v in 
         let v2 := mk_left v1 in
         let v3 := unfold_forall v2 in
         let v4 := mk_right v1 in
         let v5 := unfold_forall v4 in 
         assert v3 by apply H;
         assert v5 by apply H
 end.

Goal (forall x y z : nat, (x = z) <-> (z = y)) -> False.
intros H.
my_tac H.
```

Comment: Wow, it is much more complex than I expected! I think I get the gist of it, but I’ll take a closer look at the mechanism in my next free time. Thanks a lot!